# Xamarin forms read local json file and display in picker

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.forms, data-binding, picker

I am trying to parse a json file of contacts into a list and display that list to the user in a picker on my page displaying the contact names.

I have a json file in the root of my project called "contacts.json" and its build action is set to embedded resource.

my contacts.json file

```
{
  "contacts": [
    {
      "name": "JOE",
      "email": "name@handle",
      "phoneNumber": "123-456-7890"
    },
    {
      "name": "JYM",
      "email": "name@handle",
      "phoneNumber": "123-456-7890"
    }
  ]
}
```

my contact model:

```
    public partial class RootObject
    {
        [JsonProperty("contacts")]
        public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Contact
    {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("phoneNumber")]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

my page viewmodel where i implement a json parser

```
    public partial class Page10 : BaseViewModel
    {
        private List<Contact> _contacts;
        public List<InternalContact> contacts
        {
            get { return _contacts; }
            set
            {
                _contacts = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("contacts");
            }
        }

        public Page10()
        {
            Title = "Spill Info";
            contacts = GetJsonData();
        }

        private List<Contact> GetJsonData()
        {
            string jsonFileName = "contacts.json";
            RootObject ObjContactList = new RootObject();


            var assembly = typeof(Page10).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
            Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"{assembly.GetName().Name}.{jsonFileName}");
            using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
            {
                var jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();

                //Converting JSON Array Objects into generic list    
                ObjContactList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
            }   
            return ObjContactList.Contacts;
        }
    }
```

my baseViewModel

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        string title = string.Empty;
        public string Title
        {
            get { return title; }
            set { SetProperty(ref title, value); }
        }

        protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T backingStore, T value,
            [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "",
            Action onChanged = null)
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingStore, value))
                return false;

            backingStore = value;
            onChanged?.Invoke();
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            var changed = PropertyChanged;
            if (changed == null)
                return;

            changed.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

my page.xaml.cs

```
public partial class Page10 : ContentPage
    {
        public Page10()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.BindingContext = new contactviewmodel();
        }
    }
```

my page xaml

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Picker Title="contacts" ItemsSource="{Binding contacts}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"/>    
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

After trying the above i get an empty picker when selected but i would expect to have seen JOE and JYM in the picker.

**edit 1:** I managed to get them to display in a list so i fiddled with trying to get them into a picker from there but i am only getting a list of my object types and not names in the picker. updated code to reflect changes.
[image of phone w/ contact list view and picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tz8YC.png) (cant embed pictures yet, not enough rep).

**edit2:** modified code to show @Cherry Bu- MSFT 's implementation

Comment: `myContactList` needs to be a public property - ie, have a `get;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to your description, I do one sample that you can take a look:

```
public partial class Page10 : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<Contact> _contacts;
    public List<Contact> contacts
    {
        get { return _contacts; }
        set
        {
            _contacts = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("contacts");

        }
    }

    public Page10()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        contacts = GetJsonData();


        this.BindingContext = this;
    }

   private List<Contact> GetJsonData()
    {
        string jsonFileName = "contacts.json";
        ContactList ObjContactList = new ContactList();


        var assembly = typeof(Page10).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
        Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"{assembly.GetName().Name}.{jsonFileName}");
        using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
        {
            var jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();

            //Converting JSON Array Objects into generic list    
            ObjContactList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ContactList>(jsonString);
        }

        return ObjContactList.contacts;
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;      
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

public partial class ContactList
{
    [JsonProperty("contacts")]
    public List<Contact> contacts { get; set; }
}

public partial class Contact
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("phoneNumber")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}

  <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="MyListView" ItemsSource="{Binding contacts}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell Detail="{Binding Email}" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

        <Picker
            x:Name="MyPicker"
            ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding contacts}" />
    </StackLayout>
```

Please don't forget to implement **INotifyPropertychanged** interface to nofity data updated.

**Update:**

If you want to get local Json file and display data in ListView using mvvm, please take a look the following code, I use Mvvm Mode.

```
 public partial class Page10 : ContentPage
{
    public Page10()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.BindingContext = new contactviewmodel();
    }   

}

public class contactviewmodel:ViewModelBase
{
    private List<Contact> _contacts;
    public List<Contact> contacts
    {
        get { return _contacts; }
        set
        {
            _contacts = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("contacts");

        }
    }

    public contactviewmodel()
    {
        contacts = GetJsonData();
    }
    private List<Contact> GetJsonData()
    {
        string jsonFileName = "contacts.json";
        ContactList ObjContactList = new ContactList();


        var assembly = typeof(Page10).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
        Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"{assembly.GetName().Name}.{jsonFileName}");
        using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
        {
            var jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();

            //Converting JSON Array Objects into generic list    
            ObjContactList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ContactList>(jsonString);
        }
        //Binding listview with json string     
        return ObjContactList.contacts;
    }

}
```

The ViewModelBase is the class that implementing INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
 public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;      
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**Update again:**

You can use the following code to get Json file.

```
 private void LoadData()
    {
        var assembly = typeof(Page10).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
        foreach (var res in assembly.GetManifestResourceNames())
        {
            if (res.Contains("contacts1.json"))
            {
                Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(res);

                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    string data = "";
                    while ((data = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. maybe my understanding of MVVM is wrong but shouldn't the bulk of your code from `public partial class Page10` be in the Page10ViewModel.cs file and not the Page10.xaml.cs file? the view model is to link the user interface to your data right?

Comment: @tbarlett17 If you want to do your project using MVVM mode, please take my updated code.My previous code was not written strictly according to the mvvm mode.

Comment: @tbartleet17 If my reply help you, please don't forget to remember to mark my reply as answer, thanks.

Comment: thanks for the response. I have implemented what you have here but my picker has no options inside it when clicked on and im not sure why. I have updated the code i have in the original post, would you mind taking a look at it to see if i missed something?

Comment: please disregard the last comment. I changed from using List<T> to ObservableCollection<T> and it seems to be working now. I do have one other question though regarded the stream for the deserializer. if i wanted to organize my json files from inside the project root to a folder in the project how can i do that? instead of myproject/contacts.json i could put it in the folder named AppData. myproject/AppData/contacts.json